# How can I get the value of an output using EventEmitter?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that emit a simple string when clicking on it

The HTML of my component:

```html
<div (click)="emitSomething($event)"></div>
```

The TypeScript of my component:

```
@Output() someString: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

emitSomething(event: string) {
  this.someString.emit(event)
}
```

Now, I want to pass this simple string to another component so I can use it in my other component, how do I do that?

What I tried in the second component:

```html
<component-one (someString)="variable"></component-one>
```

The TypeScript of my second component:

```
@Output() someString: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

variable: string; // This variable should have the string value of my first component
```

EDIT: Here is what the console outputs when I do this

`Can't bind to 'someString' since it isn't a known property of 'component-one'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function that assigns the string in your parent component:

```
public assignString(input: string){
    this.variable = input;
}
```

and use it like that:

```
<component-one (someString)="assignString($event)"></component-one>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can assign emitted value directly to some variable of parent component from child component like below

```
<component-one (someString)="variable = $event"></component-one>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'another compoment' has to be the parent of this component where you emit the value using `EventEmmiter`. In your parent component do this:

```
<child-component (someString)="someStringFunction($event)"></child-component>
```

Then you can have a function in your parent component:

```
public someStringFunction(eventValue: string){
    this.variable = eventValue;
}
```